# PHP/MySql/Jquery script vs RAM

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, apache, ram

Hi guys I have a question about server's RAM and PHP/MySQL/Jquery script.

Can scripts kills RAM when script doesn't take extra RAM? (I know it could happen when RAM grow up to maximum or because of memory limit. But it isn't this case.)

I'm testing script but everytime when I do that RAM goes quickly down.
Script doesn't show error for memory limit and it's correctly loading all data. When I don't test script RAM is still down.

In database is a couple records - maybe 350 records in 9 tables (the bigges tables has 147 records).

(I haven't any logs just simply (really simple) graph for running server.)

Thank for your time.

Comment: Hm. Firstable which RAM you want to monitor? PHP/MySQL takes server RAM, jQuery takes Client RAM. Which one you consider there?

Comment: The script can't kill RAM, but it can be written to consume less RAM :)

Comment: thank you. I'm thinkig it too but never know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting errors in your PHP error log about failing to allocate memory, and you're not seeing other problems with your server running out of RAM (such as extreme performance degradation due to memory pages being written to disk for demand paging) you probably don't need to really worry about it.  Any use case where a web server uses up that much memory in a single request is going to be pretty rare.

As for trying to profile the actual memory usage, trying to profile it by watching something like the task manager is going to be pretty unreliable.  Most PHP scripts are going to complete in milliseconds, which isn't enough time for the memory allocations to really even register in the task manager.

Even if you have a more reliable method of profiling the memory usage (I don't recall if PHP has built in functions for this, but probably does), bear in mind that memory usage is going to flucuate tremendously for reasons that may be hard to understand.  PHP in particular is very high level: you can open a database connection, which involves everything down to the OS opening network sockets, creating internal datastructures, caching things, and much more all in a single line of code.  The script may allocate many megabytes of memory for such a thing for a single database row, but may then deallocate it a millisecond later.

Those database sizes are pretty neglibible.  Depending on the row sizes it's possibly under a megabyte of data which is a tiny drop in a bucket for memory on anything remotely modern.  Don't worry about memory usage for something like that.  Only if you see your scripts failing and your error log reports running out of memory should you really worry about it.

Comment: Thank you ... error log is empty and load time for script is from 0,009 to 0,02 so I guess it will be somewhere else